# How to get the list of all friends of a given person in prolog?

Tags: prolog, failure-slice, prolog-setof

I'm a beginner in Prolog, and I just want to get the list of all friends of a given person.
if i have predicates, like:

```
friend(hend, khadija).
friend(huda, mariam).
friend(huda, aisha).
friend(huda, lamia).
friend(mariam, hagar).
```

how can i write a predicate **friendList**(X,List) that store all friends of given person in List, like:

```
?- friendList(huda, List).
 List = [mariam, aisha, lamia].
```

I have tried to write this:

```
friendList(X,[]):-
   not(friend(X,_)).
friendList(X,L):-
    friend(X,Y),
    friendList(X,T),
    L = [Y|T].
```

but I get *stack limit error*.
how can i write it correctly, without built-in predicate?

Comment: Can use https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=findall/3

Comment: it was so usefull, thanks so much

Answer (score 1):

```
?- friend(huda, F).
   F = mariam
;  F = aisha
;  F = lamia.
?- setof(F, friend(huda, F), Fs).
   Fs = [aisha,lamia,mariam].
```

Your definition cannot work because of the following [failure-slice](/questions/tagged/failure-slice):

```
friendList(X,[]):- false,
   \+ friend(X,_).
friendList(X,L):-
    friend(X,Y),
    friendList(X,T), false,
    L = [Y|T].

?- friendList(huda, List), false.
   loops.
```

*Because* this fragment already loops, also your original program loops. You need to change something in the remaining visible part.

Comment: it was so usefull, thanks so much.
I wana ask how can I implement `setof` predicate by myself?

Comment: Implementing `setof/3` is pretty complex as it has to handle the general case. It is definitely not a beginners' task.

Comment: You are right, I have traied to see its implementation and it seems like advanced topic
it's just a task in my collage to find list of frind attached to some person
really thank you so much for your answer, comments, and your time.